# How can I parallelise this C# algorithm?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am a beginner C# coder so I don't know anything about Task or threads. I wrote this code and I want to use some kind of Parallel or Thread processing.

The code consist in two DataTable (A & B) and I have to compare each cell value of A to all cells of B. B consist in one column and several rows. A can be millions of cells. I do it using for loops. this is the part of the code I would like to parallelize to speed up the process:

```
  private DataTable CalculosPrincipales(DataTable Prof, DataTable Prop, DataTable Rango)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Prof Evaluar", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Profundidad", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Promedio", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Sumatoria", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("n", typeof(double));

            if (int.TryParse(box_Z.Text, out int z))
            {

            }
            var step = (progressBar.Properties.Maximum - (Int32)progressBar.EditValue)/z;

            for (int i = 0; i < Rango.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(Rango.Rows[i][0], Rango.Rows[i][1], 0, 0 , 0);
            }

            double prof_celda;
            double prof_rango;
            double prop_celda;

            for (int i = 0; i < Prop.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Prop.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    prop_celda = Convert.ToDouble(Prop.Rows[i][j]);

                    if (prop_celda != nullvalue)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < Rango.Rows.Count; k++)
                        {
                            prof_celda = Convert.ToDouble(Prof.Rows[i][j]);
                            prof_rango = Convert.ToDouble(Rango.Rows[k][0]);

                            if (prof_celda < prof_rango)
                            {
                                dt.Rows[k][3] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[k][3]) + prop_celda;
                                dt.Rows[k][4] =  Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[k][4]) + 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                progressBar.PerformStep();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][4]) == 0)
                {
                    dt.Rows[i].Delete();
                    i -= 1;
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

This code runs fast if tabla A has 10000 of cells, it takes 5 min when  200000 cells and 20 min when 1000000.

Comment: For starters, `Application.DoEvents();` remove that line

Comment: To agree with @Çöđěxěŕ, `Application.DoEvents()` makes your UI responsive, but it can also lead to weird side effects.  Consider using the `BackgroundWorker` component to do the work (and letting it marshal the progress back to the UI thread).  How do you populate your datatables?  There may be a way to populate them that doesn't require all the conversions you are doing?

Comment: the data table are populated from a external txt file... Im reading each line, then splitting those line and each item is assigned to a cell in the datatable.

Comment: as I said before, I'm not a coder, this is a hobby and Im self leaning C#, the best solution from me to show the progress bar was doevents, some one here suggested that because my level of knowledge and it worked for me. I don't understand backgroundworker at all. would be glad to know how but haven't figured out yet.

Comment: @Flydog57 I think nowadays we should use `Task.Run` instead of `BackgroudWorker`. Check [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html)

Comment: thank U... I would read it.

Comment: @calarez - It would be great if you could provide a [mcve]. Right now there is too many undefined things in your code. Good answers come from well asked questions.

Comment: I can share anything you need, the problem is I hace two tables (numerical values both) one big datable A (36 rows x 5600 collum) and one small datatable B (50 rows x 4 column) and I need to go cell by cell of datatable A and compare each cell with all cells of datatable B, row 1. I'm checking the first row of datatable B where the value of the cell is less or equal. when this happen, I Sum the cell value to datatable B, row 2 and then go to another cell and the loop continues.

Comment: @calarez, you mention 2 tables (`TabA`, `TabB`, I presume?) but what are these: `Prof`, `Rango`? (and then all of a sudden there is `dt`). Please give some clarity around those variables.

Comment: sorry, was a mistake edited the original code to have more general names, now I have copy the code as it is. DT is the ouput datatable that i need to generat so I can pass it to another sub to generate some plots.

Comment: the code is doing what I want, but i want to parallelise it or use some threads to speed up the calculations. because Im testing with a small number fo data but it would be use to with data in the order of 1 -2 millions cels.

Comment: Put the values `Rango.Rows[..][0]` into a simple array `double[Rango.Rows.Count]`. Then use a binary search into that array to find the value rather than the inner nested k loop. Before you think about parallelizing an algorithm you should make it efficient. DataTable access vs. double[] access and faster lookup. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Similarly, build your result in an array and copy it to the DataTable afterwards. e.g. an int[] array called count: `count[k]++` is going to be a lot faster than `dt.Rows[k][4] =  Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[k][4]) + 1`

Comment: There is a very good chance that parallelizing a simple mathematical operation like this will make it slower not faster, threads aren't 'cheap', instead you should first improve the algorithm to reduce the number of operations and then you should look at the core operations to make them efficient. You can also look to see if your can use operations that can be vectorized. And chances are after you've done all that you will not need to use threads to add and compare simple numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of parallelisation of your algorithm. However, using the DataTable introduces some performance penalties. You should consider using more suitable classes.

I made the following changes:

- Extracted the calculation into a separate class.
- Split the calculation into n tasks.
- Added support for cancellation via CancellationTokenSource
- Replaced active progress reporting with passive one.
- Added exception handling

Everything now works in the background. You no longer block or slow down the UI, you just execute the calculation and let it call you back when it finishes.

You can set the number of threads manually, or you can let the algorithm use the the number of CPU cores, which maximizes the performance.

Please note that it's not an ideal implementation, it's just an an example and it's not tested.

It seems to me, that your description does not quite match the code (you talked about 2 input tables, but the code works with 3 - aren't Prop and Prof the same?)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ParallelCalculation
{
    public delegate void CompletionHandler(DataTable result, Exception exception);
    public DataTable Prof, Prop, Rango;

    class Part
    {
        public DataTable Result;
        public int FromRow, ToRow;
        public float Progress;
        public Exception Exception;
    }

    DataTable result;
    Part[] parts;
    Task[] tasks;
    CancellationToken cancellation;
    CompletionHandler callback;

    public async void Run(CompletionHandler callback, CancellationToken token, int threadCount = 0)
    {
        this.cancellation = token;
        this.callback = callback;

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(Perform, threadCount);
    }

    async void Perform(object state)
    {
        int threadCount = (int)state;

        try
        {
            // Create table for results
            result = new DataTable();
            result.Columns.Add("Prof Evaluar", typeof(double));
            result.Columns.Add("Profundidad", typeof(double));
            result.Columns.Add("Promedio", typeof(double));
            result.Columns.Add("Sumatoria", typeof(double));
            result.Columns.Add("n", typeof(double));

            for (int i = 0; i < Rango.Rows.Count; i++)
                result.Rows.Add(Rango.Rows[i][0], Rango.Rows[i][1], 0, 0, 0);

            // Split calculation into n tasks. Tasks work in parallel,
            // each one processes it's own stripe of data, defined by the instance of the Part class.
            int n = threadCount > 0 ? threadCount : Environment.ProcessorCount;
            tasks = new Task[n];
            parts = new Part[n];
            int rowsPerTask = Prof.Rows.Count / n;
            int rest = Prof.Rows.Count % n;
            for (int i = 0, from = 0, to = 0; i < n; ++i, --rest, from = to)
            {
                to = from + rowsPerTask + (rest > 0 ? 1 : 0);
                parts[i] = new Part { FromRow = from, ToRow = to };
                tasks[i] =  Task.Factory.StartNew(CalculatePart, parts[i]);
            }

            // Wait until all partial calculations are finished
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            // Sum partial results to the main result table (and find the first exception, if any)
            Exception e = null;
            foreach (var part in parts)
            {
                e = e ?? part.Exception;
                for (int row = 0; row < result.Rows.Count; ++row)
                {
                    result.Rows[row][3] = Convert.ToDouble(result.Rows[row][3]) + Convert.ToDouble(part.Result.Rows[row][3]);
                    result.Rows[row][4] = Convert.ToInt32(result.Rows[row][4]) + Convert.ToInt32(part.Result.Rows[row][4]);
                }
            }

            // Remove empty rows from results
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(result.Rows[i][4]) == 0)
                {
                    result.Rows[i].Delete();
                    i -= 1;
                }
            }

            // Call back 
            callback?.Invoke(result, e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            callback?.Invoke(null, e);
        }
    }

    void CalculatePart(object state)
    {
        var part = (Part)state;
        try
        {
            // Create our own table for partial results.
            part.Result = this.result.Copy();

            var result = part.Result; // Just a shortcut

            int cols = Prop.Columns.Count;
            int steps = cols * (part.ToRow - part.FromRow);

            for (int i = part.FromRow, step = 1; i < part.ToRow; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++, step++)
                {
                    var prop_celda_obj = Prop.Rows[i][j];
                    if (prop_celda_obj != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        double prop_celda = Convert.ToDouble(prop_celda_obj);
                        double prof_celda = Convert.ToDouble(Prof.Rows[i][j]);

                        for (int k = 0; k < Rango.Rows.Count; k++)
                        {
                            //double prof_celda = Convert.ToDouble(Prof.Rows[i][j]);
                            double prof_rango = Convert.ToDouble(Rango.Rows[k][0]);

                            if (prof_celda < prof_rango)
                            {
                                result.Rows[k][3] = Convert.ToDouble(result.Rows[k][3]) + prop_celda;
                                result.Rows[k][4] = Convert.ToDouble(result.Rows[k][4]) + 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    part.Progress = step / (float)steps;
                    if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            part.Exception = e;
        }
    }

    public float Progress()
    {
        float sum = 0.0f;
        foreach (var part in parts)
            sum += part.Progress;
        return sum / parts.Length;
    }
}
```

The following code is an example of using the above class in a Form. You'll have to adapt it a bit, probably.

```
partial class MyForm {   

    Button btnStartStop;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    // Do this somewhere:
    // btnStartStop.Click += BtnStartStop_Click;

    int threads = 0;              // 0 means "The number of CPU cores"
    DataTable Prof, Prop, Rango;  // You have to provide these values

    // The final results will be stored here:
    DataTable Result;

    CancellationTokenSource cancellation;
    ParallelCalculation calculation;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer progressTimer;

    void BtnStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculation != null)
            cancellation.Cancel();
        else
            StartCalculation();
    }

    void StartCalculation()
    {
        cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        calculation = new ParallelCalculation { Prof = this.Prof, Prop = this.Prop, Rango = this.Rango };
        calculation.Run(Finished, cancellation.Token, threads);

        progressBar.Value = 0;
        progressTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(components) { Interval = 100 };
        progressTimer.Tick += ProgressTimer_Tick;
        progressTimer.Start();

        UpdateUI();
    }

    void Finished(DataTable table, Exception e)
    {
        BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            Result = table;
            progressBar.Value = (int)(calculation.Progress() * 100);
            progressTimer.Stop();
            progressTimer.Tick -= ProgressTimer_Tick;
            calculation = null;

            UpdateUI();
        });
    }

    private void ProgressTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculation != null)
            progressBar.Value = (int)(calculation.Progress() * 100);
    }

    void UpdateUI()
    {
        btnStartStop.Text = calculation == null ? "Start" : "Stop";
    }
}
```